# Checking if a worksheet-based checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, vba, macos, checkbox

I'm trying to use an IF-clause to determine whether my checkbox, named "Check Box 1", is checked.

My current code:

```
Sub Button167_Click()
 If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1") = True Then
 Range("Y12").Value = 1
 Else
 Range("Y12").Value = 0
 End If
End Sub
```

This doesn't work. The debugger is telling me there is a problem with the

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1")
```

However, I know this code works (even though it serves a different purpose):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").Select
With Selection
.Value = xlOn
```

My checkboxes (there are 200 on my page), are located in sheet1, by the name of "Demande". Each Checkbox is has the same formatted name of "Check Box ...".

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").Value = True`?

Comment: form control checkbox or active x control checkbox?

Comment: @Motes Any way to quickly know, without me having to boot up Parallels?

Comment: Hi, can you please help me to get value of checkbox in javascript in same manner

Comment: You can find another solution using `CodeName` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36921631/1946796)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
Sub Button167_Click()
 If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
 Range("Y12").Value = 1
 Else
 Range("Y12").Value = 0
 End If
End Sub
```

1 is checked, -4146 is unchecked, 2 is mixed (grey box)

Comment: This worked like a charm. @Siddharth, your answer is correct as well

Comment: how to get the value you in javascript code after parsing the excel file. I need the chekbox value from excel workbook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064853/parse-the-excel-workbook-and-get-the-checkbox-value-in-javascipt-or-angular

Comment: FYI -4146 == xlOff and 1 == xlOn

Comment: @tomatoeshift And 2 = `xlMixed`.

Answer (score 12):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim cb As Shape

    Set cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1")

    If cb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Checkbox is Checked"
    Else
        MsgBox "Checkbox is not Checked"
    End If
End Sub
```

Replace `Activesheet` with the relevant sheetname. Also replace `Check Box 1` with the relevant checkbox name.

Comment: This will check the box, but to read it you need to set check the value against 1.

Comment: +1 I didn't know this before. I'm going to delete my reply as it may lead to confusion. Just tried it and indd it works. In this case checked seems to be verified by values 1 and 0 (not true and false).

Comment: @Motes: Yes. I have added that part. I was reading the post from blackberry so misread it. I thought the user wanted to check the checkbox. :P

Comment: If you reused the shape reference, it might be more efficient, and he probably made it this way for readability.

Comment: @PaoloBernasconi: Could you please explain what do you mean by less efficient and how is it less efficient?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, sorry less efficient is the wrong word to use. Motes's code is just shorter, even though I'm sure the executing time is the same for both of your answers.

Comment: @PaoloBernasconi: Ok. Fair enough :)

Answer (score 7):

In VBA macro code for an **ActiveX** checkbox control, you use

```vb
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True Then
```

and for a **Form** checkbox control, you use

```vb
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOn Then
```

(Use `xlOff` or `xlMixed` to check for these respective states.)

Answer (score 4):

Building on the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742520/190829) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742718/190829), you can leverage the fact that `True` is -1 and `False` is 0 and shorten your code like this:

```
Sub Button167_Click()
  Range("Y12").Value = _
    Abs(Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value > 0)
End Sub
```

If the checkbox is checked, `.Value` = 1.

`Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value > 0` returns `True`.

Applying the `Abs` function converts `True` to `1`.

If the checkbox is unchecked, `.Value` = -4146.

`Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value > 0` returns `False`.

Applying the `Abs` function converts `False` to `0`.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me to get value of checkbox in javascript in same manner

Answer (score -2):

Try: `Controls("Check Box 1") = True`