# how to link a checkbox on Excel to a VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have created a checkbox on my Excel Work sheet, using design mode I have leftclicked it and named it ChkV, and I wrote a VBA code but when I run it I get an message telling that the variable is not defined.

```
    If ChkV.Value = True Then
        ' my code
    End If
```

Did I not label the check box correctly, what am I doing wrong ? How should I fix the mistake?

Comment: Right-click it, choose Properties, and look at the (Name) field. Is it really named `ChkV`? Or did you just change the caption to say ChkV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should it not be

```
If  activesheet.Checkboxes("ChkV") = xlOn Then
'your code
End If
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You have this error when you call your code outside `Sheet module` where your `checkbox` is located. To improve your code you need to add references to sheet where `checkbox` belongs to, like:

```
If Sheets("Sheet 1").ChkV.Value = True Then
    ' my code
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was breaking my head over and over again for this, but searching i found that you need to refer by the `CodeName`'s sheet or using `OleObjects`

1. By `Code Name` is how you see in the [VBA Project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjjWr.jpg):

   ```
   Hoja1.[CheckBoxName].Value  
   '' In English or what ever you may call your sheet is:
   Sheet1.[CheckBoxName].Value
   ```
2. By `OleObjects` is:

   ```
   Dim Wks as Worksheet  
   Set Wks = Worksheets("[SheetName]")    '' in this case "Prueba"
   Wks.OLEObjects("[CheckBoxName]").Object.Value
   ```

*Note that my Excel is in Spanish thats why you see `Hoja1`, in English is `Sheet1` and you can find something else [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841148.aspx).*

[image: VBAProject tree]