# Excel unchecking check box vbokcancel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to get the cancel button in my message box that pops up when I check the box to uncheck the checked box.  I've gotten the box to pop up, but my cancel button produces "Run Time error 438".

My current code is as follows:

```
Sub Checkbox1()

Dim msgRes As VbMsgBoxResult

msgRes = MsgBox("Please review your changes.    If correct, click OK", _
                 vbOKCancel)

If msgRes = vbCancel Then
Sheets("sheet1").Checkbox1.Value = False

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: If I remove Sheets("sheet1").Checkbox1.Value = False this line code works fine. What exactly is the problem and at which line?

Comment: I have no vba editor at hand, but could it be, that you have to write `Sheets("Sheet1").Checkbox1.Value = False` ? "sheet1" and "Sheet1" shouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Think your problem is related to this answer

[Checking if a worksheet-based checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742718/692942)

Give this a try;

```vb
If msgRes = vbCancel Then
    Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Checkbox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = True
End If
```

Comment: @ChristianF.Pajusi .. you must make a green check below the downvote sign .. since it helped you