# parse the excel workbook and get the checkbox value in javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vba, excel

I am parsing the excel file to get all the data from Excel workbook, I am using [js-xlsx Plugin from github](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/README.md)

Currently my all value are getting read in JavaScript but now I want to accept the value of the checkbox from excel workbook. whether is checked or not. Chk following example from sample workbook.

[image: img]

is there any way to get the value of this check box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this with a small trick, in Excel file place one cell which maps to this check-box, when check-box is checked updated the value of cell as 1 and if check-box is unchecked then value of this cell is zero.

As I can read the simple Excel cell value, according to this hidden cell value we get whether the check-box is checked or not.