# Is there a JavaScript Excel parser that can read checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, excel, parsing

I've been tasked with parsing Excel sheets and saving their data. Unfortunately, the template for these sheets includes checkboxes that I don't seem able to read.

[A single cell might have two checkboxes in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baWB8.png), but the value I get from parsers is simply `value: '    CWS      NTNCWS'` regardless of either box being checked.

I've tried using SheetJS and ExcelJS - `worksheet.A9` and `worksheet.getCell('A9').value`, respectively - but each gives me something like the string value above that doesn't reference the checkbox values. I also know I could [create a hidden cell in the Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34084848/22875005) that gives me a numerical value based on the checkboxes, but unfortunately the template these files are based on is already public-facing, so we can no longer modify it.

Is there any Excel parser for JavaScript that can read the values of these checkboxes? I also have the ability to manipulate these files however I want, but I can't change the template they're based on, and this needs to be a fully automated process.

Update/Incomplete answer: It looks like there are no free excel parsers that handle this use case, though as @PeterT pointed out SheetJS supports form control parsing in their Pro builds.

Comment: I don't use SheetJS, but found a [statement](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/2208) that "'Form controls' are stored elsewhere and are currently supported in our Pro builds but not in the open source".

Comment: Can you save the file as xml and use an xml parser?

Comment: @PeterT Thank you for confirming that; I saw something similar, but I'm quite confident my small-ish company won't shell out for anything that can be done for free, even if the free version requires major workarounds.

Comment: You could probably add support yourself... Save the file without a checkbox checked, then with a checkbox checked; assuming XLSX files, they're ZIP files you can decompress and compare with a suitable tool (e.g. Beyond Compare) to figure out where checkiness is stored, and go from there. It's probably not trivial, but...