# Add bcc address if checkbox True

Tags: excel, vba

I am building an email in Excel for Outlook using the following code:

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Volume Template").Range("K4:L14").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC =
        .Subject = "UTS VOLUME QUOTE REQUEST"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

I want to use check boxes (using form controls) to decide whether an email is used.

If the check box reference cell is true input the value of a cell (an email address) into the BCC field.

If Cell H4=True return Cell F4.

Going down a list of about 26 entries so this will need to loop until no more check boxes

How do I write this code?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I write the VBA code to                                                                In the .BCC = Field I want to reference if the a reference cell is true to input the value of the email cell (an email address) into the BCC field. 

So if Cell H4=True return Cell F4 and If Cell H4=False don't input anything

Answer (score 1):

Add this after your **`On Error GoTo 0`** line

```
Dim bccEmail As String
If Sheets("Volume Template").Range("H4").Value = True Then
    bccEmail = Sheets("Volume Template").Range("F4").Value
Else
    bccEmail = ""
End If
```

And then replace **`.BCC =`** with **`.BCC = bccEmail`** in your **`With...End With`**.

Comment: When I input the code it did not return an email address when H4 was true. Also, will this work for multiple true fields so if H5=True return F5 H7=True Return F7 and so one.

Comment: My code is tested and working properly. How you have written `True` in your SS? To make it work for multiple row, you need to put that in `Loop`. I don't know how many rows you have.

Comment: It is a checkbox that if checked it is referencing the cell and inputting true of false.

Comment: So you have a checkbox in cell `H4`? Which kind of checkbox? You need to ask your question with proper details. Folks here will answer accordingly.

Comment: It is a checkbox using Developer under Insert>Form Contrls. Thank you I will try to ask my question with better details. I am very new to this and keep getting additional request from my boss

Comment: To handle those check boxes, you need to check this [**`post`**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11741836/1652222).