# Loop to extract value from checkbox

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

A form I am working with has 10 checkboxes, with values 1 through 10, used to answer a multiple choice question.

Multiple values are technically possible (clicking on multiple boxes), but they are not allowed (while filling, only one value should be given). I cannot modify this form so I have to work with this setup.

I need to extract the given choice and paste it into a different worksheet.
Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741836/checking-if-a-worksheet-based-checkbox-is-checked) I can extract the value of every single checkbox and develop a IF Loop.

```
If ExtractionSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then

Database.Cells(5, 9).Value = 1

ElseIf ExtractionSheet.Shapes("Check Box 2").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then

Database.Cells(5, 9).Value = 2

ElseIf ExtractionSheet.Shapes("Check Box 3").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then

Database.Cells(5, 9).Value = 3

...
```

However, this does not look very efficient (I have 3 sets of 1-10 checkboxes per form and 100+ forms). Given the setup, I cannot figure out a better way to do it.

**How can I improve the extraction without using an IF loop?**

**EDIT** A better description of the form, following comments

This is a simple excel worksheet, in which 3 groups of 10 check box elements were pasted.

Each form/worksheet relates to a single item. During the assessment, for each item we will assign a value between 1 and 10 to Property 1 (first 10 check boxes), a value between 1 and 10 to Property 2 (second 10 check boxes) and a value between 1 and 10 to Property 3 (third 10 check boxes).

I will do the filling (physically clicking the box) while in front of the client who is giving me data to fill it. The possibility of clicking multiple boxes naturally exists; I do not think it will be critical because many people will be looking at the screen while I do it, but I can always add a check later on.

Comment: An `If` is not a loop - It is a statement. A `For` or `Do` is used for a loop

Comment: Are these on a user form?

Comment: Could you add an event on the form so that if another is selected the previous one is auto unselected?

Comment: @Tom No. But I could check during the extraction if there are two or more variables selected and issue a warning.

Comment: @SJR Yes, they are on an Excel user form that my client provided and that will fill out with me. I will actually do the filling (box clicking etc.)

Comment: @laureapresa If they are on a userform where is the initial information coming from?

Comment: @Tom I edited the question to include a better explanation of the form structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated after comments:

I have used the following naming convention for the `checkboxes` (Using just e.g. A1 is a cell reference and could cause problems)

```
ChkBox_A1
```

Where the first part denotes that it is a `checkbox` (`ChkBox`), second the group `A` and third the position `1`. With this naming convention and how the code is currently written you will be able to have a maximum of 26 groups (i.e. one for every letter of the alphabet)

I use the immediate window for the results which can be accessed in the VBA editor by going to `View`->`Immediate Window` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

This code will handle single select per group. i.e. If a checkbox is selected in the group it will un-select all other ones

***For a worksheet***

*This code goes in the worksheet object*

Replace all of the click statements (e.g. `ChkBox_A1_Click()` with reference to your own. This can be easily done by calling the `GenerateChkBoxClickStmt` sub and copying and pasting the output in the immediate window into your code (replacing my ones)

```
Option Explicit
Dim ChkBoxChange As Boolean
Private Sub ChkBox_A1_Click()
    If ChkBoxChange = False Then UnselectPreviousChkBox Me.ChkBox_A1
End Sub
Private Sub ChkBox_A2_Click()
    If ChkBoxChange = False Then UnselectPreviousChkBox Me.ChkBox_A2
End Sub
Private Sub ChkBox_B1_Click()
    If ChkBoxChange = False Then UnselectPreviousChkBox Me.ChkBox_B1
End Sub
Private Sub UnselectPreviousChkBox(selected As Object)
    Dim ChkBox As OLEObject

    ChkBoxChange = True

    For Each ChkBox In Me.OLEObjects
        If ChkBox.progID = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
            If ChkBox.Name <> selected.Name And Mid(ChkBox.Name, 8, 1) = Mid(selected.Name, 8, 1) Then
                ChkBox.Object.Value = False
            End If
        End If
    Next ChkBox

    ChkBoxChange = False
End Sub
Private Sub GenerateChkBoxClickStmt()
    Dim ChkBox As OLEObject
    ' Copy and paste output to immediate window into here

    For Each ChkBox In Me.OLEObjects
        If ChkBox.progID = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
            Debug.Print "Private Sub " & ChkBox.Name & "_Click()"
            Debug.Print vbTab & "If ChkBoxChange = False Then UnselectPreviousChkBox Me." & ChkBox.Name
            Debug.Print "End Sub"
        End If
    Next ChkBox
End Sub
```

Producing the following:

[image]

*This code goes into a Module*

```
Option Explicit
Private Function GetChkBoxValues(ChkBoxGroup As Variant) As Long
    Dim ChkBox As OLEObject

    ' Update with your sheet reference
    For Each ChkBox In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If ChkBox.progID = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
            If ChkBox.Object.Value = True And Mid(ChkBox.Name, 8, 1) = ChkBoxGroup Then
                GetChkBoxValues = Right(ChkBox.Name, Len(ChkBox.Name) - (Len("ChkBox_") + 1))
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next ChkBox
End Function
Public Sub GetSelectedChkBoxes()
    Dim ChkBoxGroups() As Variant
    Dim Grp As Variant

    ChkBoxGroups = Array("A", "B", "C")

    For Each Grp In ChkBoxGroups
        Debug.Print "Group " & Grp, GetChkBoxValues(Grp)
    Next Grp
End Sub
```

By running the `GetSelectedChkBoxes` the code will output to the immediate window:

[image]

***For a UserForm***

Similarly the statements for the click events can be generated by uncommenting the line in the `Userform_Initalize` sub

```
Option Explicit
Dim ChkBoxChange As Boolean
Private Function GetChkBoxValues(Group As Variant) As Long
    Dim ChkBox As Control

    For Each ChkBox In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ChkBox) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ChkBox.Object.Value = True And Mid(ChkBox.Name, 8, 1) = Group Then
                GetChkBoxValues = Right(ChkBox.Name, Len(ChkBox.Name) - (Len("ChkBox_") + 1))
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next ChkBox
End Function
Private Sub UnselectPreviousChkBox(selected As Control)
    Dim ChkBox As Control
    ChkBoxChange = True
    For Each ChkBox In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ChkBox) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ChkBox.Name <> selected.Name And Mid(ChkBox.Name, 8, 1) = Mid(selected.Name, 8, 1) Then
                ChkBox.Value = False
            End If
        End If
    Next ChkBox
    ChkBoxChange = False
End Sub
Private Sub ChkBox_A1_Click()
    If ChkBoxChange = False Then UnselectPreviousChkBox Me.ChkBox_A1
End Sub
Private Sub ChkBox_A2_Click()
    If ChkBoxChange = False Then UnselectPreviousChkBox Me.ChkBox_A2
End Sub
Private Sub ChkBox_B1_Click()
    If ChkBoxChange = False Then UnselectPreviousChkBox Me.ChkBox_B1
End Sub
Private Sub userform_initialize()
    ' Comment out once written
    ' GenerateChkBoxClickStmt
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Dim ChkBoxGroups() As Variant
    Dim Grp As Variant

    ChkBoxGroups = Array("A", "B", "C")

    For Each Grp In ChkBoxGroups
        Debug.Print "Group " & Grp, GetChkBoxValues(Grp)
    Next Grp
End Sub
Private Sub GenerateChkBoxClickStmt()
    Dim ChkBox As Control
    ' Copy and paste output to immediate window into here
    For Each ChkBox In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ChkBox) = "CheckBox" Then
            Debug.Print "Private Sub " & ChkBox.Name & "_Click()"
            Debug.Print vbTab & "If ChkBoxChange = False Then UnselectPreviousChkBox Me." & ChkBox.Name
            Debug.Print "End Sub"
        End If
    Next ChkBox
End Sub
```

Producing:

[image]

and outputting the following on exit:

[image]

Comment: Is there any logic between the two then?

Comment: Not at all. I could rename them to a progressive number and then apply your solution. 
How would I approach the fact that I have 3 groups of 10 check boxes per form?

Comment: How do you group them together? I'd recommend naming them with some sort of logic. If there is nothing grouping them, you could also apply a naming convention to depict which group the checkbox is related to. e.g. "Group A Checkbox 1" etc.

Comment: I can rename my check boxes as A1, A2... A10, B1, B2...B10 and so on.How would I edit your code to run only for one group?

Comment: @laureapresa Please have a look at my update. I've produced a more complex answer which will handle single select per group and account for all groups in both a `WorkSheet` method or a `UserForm`. If you have any questions feel free to ask. Please pay attention to the `GenerateChkBoxClickStmt` as these subs will generate all of the `Click` statements for you instead of having to write them (they are based off of the `CheckBox` Names so will need to be structured correctly to work. I've suggested a naming pattern for you as well